# Load files from FTP in File_FDW in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ftp, sftp

Can you help me understand if file_fdw allows to connect and read from FTP ?  How can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

file_fdw, starting in version 10, supports PROGRAM. So if you can write a program (or use existing programs) to read from ftp, you can hook file_fdw up to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, file_fdw can only access files local on the database server machine.

Perhaps `COPY ... FROM PROGRAM` is what you need:

```
COPY tab
FROM PROGRAM 'curl ftp://server.org/file';
```

But this copies the data into a database table.

Comment: Thanks.  But as per my understanding COPY FROM cannot do any ETL kind of operations.  Are you aware about any new updates on that in the latest version or so ?

Comment: I still want to read data from file.. so COPY FROM doesnt help

Comment: Then there is no way to do it with PostgreSQL tools. You will have to use something else.

Comment: There seems to be few interfaces available.  But might need to explore more.